# DT in Shiny: Change only the colour of a single row

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a dataset:

```
ID Value
102 306
41  800
101 783
105 193
myID 334
```

I would like to draw this up as a datatable where only the row with 'myID' is coloured orange and the rest of the table is blue. Having looked at the [helper functions](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html) and [other examples](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html), it seems that I should be using styleEqual. However, I don't know what the values in my other rows are, and also they will change dynamically.

I tried using

```
datatable(tableData) %>%
formatStyle(0, target= 'row',color = 'black', backgroundColor = tableColour, 
                lineHeight='70%', padding = '3px 3px', fontSize = '80%') %>%
    formatStyle('ID', target = 'row', 
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("myID"), c('orange')))
```

However, this does not work - the whole table is blue, and the second `formatStyle` statement is ignored. If I remove the first formatStyle, I get my row coloured in orange but lose all other formatting. Is there a way to use styleEqual to define e.g. `c("myID", "All other IDs")`, or is there another workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two possible workarounds:

- Create a helper column that is 1 or 0, based on if your column is equal to `myID` or not, then use that column to style the table and hide that column.
- Create a column mapping for all your unique values in the column `ID`, that defaults to a certain color, and set only the value corresponding to `myID` to orange.

A working example of the second option is given below. Hope this helps!

---

### [image]

```
df = read.table(text='ID Value
102 306
41  800
101 783
105 193
myID 334',header=T)

library(DT)

my_vals = unique(df$ID)
my_colors = ifelse(my_vals=='myID','orange','grey')

datatable(df) %>%
  formatStyle('ID', target = 'row', 
              backgroundColor = styleEqual(my_vals,my_colors))
```

Comment: I really like that second solution because it uses the current data. However a helper column is also certainly an option. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `DT` you can use `styleEqual()` to add background color to your table if the condition is met. There does not seem to be an else option, so you can create an object of class `JS_EVAL` (which would be returned by `styleEqual()`) and add a negation:

```
background <- "value == 'myID' ? 'orange' : value != 'else' ? 'blue' : ''"  
class(background) <- "JS_EVAL"

datatable(tableData) %>% formatStyle(
  'ID',
  target = 'row',
  backgroundColor = background
)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

You could also achieve it using the package `tableHTML`:

```
library(tableHTML)

tableData %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
            widths = c(100, 100)) %>% 
  add_css_row(rows = which(tableData$ID == 'myID') + 1,
              css = list(c("background-color"),
                         c("orange"))) %>% 
  add_css_row(rows = which(tableData$ID != 'myID') + 1,
              css = list(c("background-color"),
                         c("blue")))
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is also really helpful, thank you. I can't use tableHTML because the table also has dynamic sorting and column selection, but the JS_EVAL route would definitely work.

Comment: Really nice solution! Could you elaborate a bit on how you got to this solution? How do you know to use the word 'value'? in the statement? PS: In trying to find out how your solution works, I did find out that you could alternatively use `JS()` to create an object of class `JS_EVAL` in one line.

Comment: thank you! :)it was a step by step approach, first I used `styleEqual("myID", "orange")` to add orange to one row, I then couldn't find a way to add negation and checked the output of the function, changed it and used it.