# Shiny: Using selections from timevis to highlight rows in data table

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app with a timeline and a data table. What I would like to have happen is when the user clicks on an item in the timeline, the corresponding data in the table is highlighted.

I have come up with a solution for this, but it seems very hacky and R is giving me warning messages. Basically what I have done is created a flag in the data table that is 1 if that item is selected and 0 if it's not, then I format the row based on that flag. When I create the "selected" field, I get a warning because initially nothing is selected and mutate doesn't like the fact that input$timeline_selected is NULL. Also for some reason when I try to add the `rownames = FALSE` argument to `datatable` all the data in the table is filtered out (not sure what is happening there).

Anyway, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this perhaps with HTML or CSS. I've tried looking, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Eventually I would also like to know how to highlight the rows in the data table if the user hovers over the item in the timeline rather than selects it.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

dataBasic <- data.frame(
  id = 1:4,
  content = c("Item one", "Item two" ,"Ranged item", "Item four"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11", "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14"),
  end    = c(NA, NA, "2016-02-04", NA)
)



ui <- fluidPage(
  column(wellPanel(timevisOutput("timeline")
                   ), width = 7
         ),
  column(wellPanel(dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
                   ), width = 5)
  )

server <- function(input, output){
  # Create timeline
  output$timeline <- renderTimevis({
    config <- list(
      orientation = "top",
      multiselect = TRUE
    )
      timevis(dataBasic, options = config)
  })


  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    input$timeline_data %>% 
      mutate(selected = if_else(id %in% input$timeline_selected, 1, 0)) %>% 
      datatable(options = list(pageLength = 10, 
                               columnDefs = list(list(targets = 5, visible = FALSE))
                               )
       ) %>% 
       formatStyle("selected", target = "row", backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c("transparent", "#0092FF"))
       )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Your Code

Your method certainly works -- it's similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49176358/8099834). You could prevent some of the error messages by using `if...else` and a [validation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html) statment:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

        validate(need(!is.null(input$timeline_data), ""))

        if(is.null(input$timeline_selected)) {
            input$timeline_data %>%
                datatable(
                    rownames = FALSE,
                    options = list(pageLength = 10))
        } else {
            input$timeline_data %>% 
                mutate(selected = if_else(id %in% input$timeline_selected, 1, 0)) %>% 
                datatable(rownames = FALSE, 
                          options = list(pageLength = 10, 
                                         columnDefs = list(list(targets = 4, visible = FALSE))
                )
                ) %>% 
                formatStyle("selected", target = "row", backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c("transparent", "#0092FF"))
                ) 
        }
    })
```

I believe your issue with adding `rownames = FALSE` is because `columnDefs` uses [JS indexing instead of R indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3135325/8099834). R indexes start at 1, whereas JS indexes start at 0.

When `rownames = TRUE`, your table has column indexes 0-5, where `rownames` is column 0 and `selected` is the column 5. So `columnDefs` works. However, when `rownames = FALSE`, you only have column indexes 0-4, so `targets = 5` is outside the index range of your table. If you change your code to `targets = 4`, then you will again be specifying the `selected` column in `columnDefs`.

### Other Options

Here's two other options using JS:

1. Generate the table on the server-side, as based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49176615/8099834). This may be a [better option for large data objects](https://blog.rstudio.com/2015/06/24/dt-an-r-interface-to-the-datatables-library/#server-side-processing).
2. Generate the table on the client-side as based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165876/8099834). With a smaller object, this seems to update more smoothly.

An example app with both tables is below.

[image]

### Example Code

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(timevis)

dataBasic <- data.frame(
    id = 1:4,
    content = c("Item one", "Item two" ,"Ranged item", "Item four"),
    start = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11", "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14"),
    end = c(NA, NA, "2016-02-04", NA)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
    column(wellPanel(timevisOutput("timeline")
    ), width = 7
    ),
    column(
        wellPanel(
            h3("Client-Side Table"),
            DT::dataTableOutput("client_table"),
            h3("Server-Side Table"),
            DT::dataTableOutput("server_table")
    ), width = 5)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

    # Create timeline
    output$timeline <- renderTimevis({
        config <- list(
            orientation = "top",
            multiselect = TRUE
        )
        timevis(dataBasic, options = config)
    })

    ## client-side ##
    # based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165876/8099834
    output$client_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        # if timeline has been selected, add JS drawcallback to datatable
        # otherwise, just return the datatable
        if(!is.null(input$timeline_selected)) {
            # subtract one: JS starts index at 0, but R starts index at 1
            index <- as.numeric(input$timeline_selected) - 1
            js <- paste0("function(row, data) {
                $(this
                     .api()
                     .row(", index, ")
                     .node())
                .css({'background-color': 'lightblue'});}")
            datatable(dataBasic,
                      rownames = FALSE,
                      options = list(pageLength = 10,
                                     drawCallback=JS(js)))
        } else {
            datatable(dataBasic,
                      rownames = FALSE,
                      options = list(pageLength = 10))
        }

    }, server = FALSE)

    ## server-side ##
    # based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49176615/8099834
    output$server_table <- DT::renderDataTable({

        # create the datatable
        dt <- datatable(dataBasic,
                        rownames = FALSE,
                        options = list(pageLength = 10))

        # if timeline has been selected, add row background colors with formatstyle
        if(!is.null(input$timeline_selected)) {
            index <- as.numeric(input$timeline_selected)
            background <- JS(paste0("value == '",
                                    index,
                                    "' ? 'lightblue' : value != 'else' ? 'white' : ''"))
            dt <- dt %>%
                formatStyle(
                    'id',
                    target = 'row',
                    backgroundColor = background)
        }

        # return the datatable
        dt
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much for your help! I would have never been able to figure this out on my own!